# How to change the Host Names without disturbing the availability of instance in Apsara DB for Mongo DB?

Tags: database, mongodb, cloud, alibaba-cloud

I understand how to change the Host Names without disturbing the availability of self-build Mongo DB Instance but I am not able to find any documentation related to doing the same on Apsara DB for Mongo DB. Can you all share any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried doing this but this is more primitive to MongoDB. 
You can do that in 2 ways:

- **Change hostnames without disrupting availability** 
   This approach ensures your applications will always be able to read and write data to the replica set, but the approach can take a long time and may incur downtime at the application layer.
- **Stop all members running on the old hostnames at once** 

  This approach has a shorter maintenance window, but the replica set will be unavailable during the operation.

You can find documentation here
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-hostnames-in-a-replica-set/#replica-set-change-hostname-no-downtime